# Is it possible to send a MediaPlayer object from service to a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, visualizer

In my android app I want to implement a visualizer graph linked to a Media Player following [this](https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/blob/master/src/com/pheelicks/app/MainActivity.java) idea. I use a service to manage my background streaming with `MediaPlayer`. The problem comes with the transmission of my `MediaPlayer` object to my fragment. I need to have it there because is where the link occurs:

```
    // We need to link the visualizer view to the media player so that
    // it displays something
    mVisualizerView = (VisualizerView) findViewById(R.id.visualizerView);
    mVisualizerView.link(mPlayer);
```

In summary, I need to send `MediaPlayer` object from my service to my fragment. Any idea?

Comment: use "bound local service" pattern

Comment: That did it. Thanks man. I followed official documentation. It works perfect :D  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: your welcome,  btw how to make sure that request.session.session_key is always != None? I created 3 line middllleware that creates a session but not sure if thats the proper way

Comment: try with `if not request.session.session_key:`

Comment: I dont want to test it in different various places, i need it to be valid session_key all the time in my view methods

Comment: Could be possible, but i'm not sure @pskink. Ask in the forum buddy. For me sounds good tho.